# jQuery to format input in a specific format

Tags: jquery

I am trying to format number through jQuery in USA phone number format. that is `(111) 111 1111` but it doesn't let me delete also it is adding 11th digit and not deleting it. Can anyone help?

```js
$("#no").keypress(function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value.length <= 10) {
   var first = "(" + value[0]+value[1]+value[2] + ")" + " " + value[3]+value[4]+value[5]+ " " + value[6]+value[7]+value[8]+value[9];
    $(this).val(first);
    $("#no_span").html(first);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if(value.length > 10) {
    $(this).val($("#no_span").html());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="no" maxlimit="14"/>
<span id="no_span"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I used switch statement to add special characters and spaces to the number. There is if statement which shows formated number when it is 10 characters or more. Hope it is what you were looking for, if you would need some different functionality let me know.

```js
$("#no").on('keyup', function()
{
  var value = $(this).val().split('')
  var output = '' 
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0: {
        output += '(' + value[i];
        break;
      }
      case 2: {
        output += value[i] + ') ';
        break;
      }
      case 5: {
        output += value[i] + ' ';
        break;
      }
      default: output += value[i]
    }    
  }
  if (value.length >= 10) 
    $('#no_span').html(output)
  else 
    $('#no_span').html('')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="no" maxlimit="14"/>
<span id="no_span"></span>
```